# Django - what happens when re_path finds a match but hands off to an "include"d urls.py file?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm working on a Django site, but fairly new to Django and Python.

I have a situation where there is a "higher level" `urls.py` file using `re_path` to do regex matching for subdirectories, and then `include` to pass off each subdirectory to its own `urls.py` file.  Something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^SUBDIR1/.*$(?i)', include('subdir1.urls')),
    re_path(r'^SUBDIR2/.*$(?i)', include('subdir2.urls')),
    re_path(r'^SUBDIR3/.*$(?i)', include('subdir3.urls'))
]
```

And then each of the subdirectories' `urls.py` basically has only one path/view hooked up:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main_view, name='index')
]
```

In one of them I'm trying to set up a second URL to go to a different view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main_view, name='index'),
    path('my_new_view/<parameter>/', views.my_new_view, name='my_new_view')
]
```

But I can't seem to get my view called, every time I try a URL that should match my new pattern, I just get the main view again.  I'm guessing I don't quite understand what's happening when `re_path` finds a match and hands off to the included `urls.py` file.  I get that the regexes are basically saying "match the subdirectory name, a forward slash, and then any number of characters afterwards", but what happens to that "matched" string? Does the full match get passed to the `include` file for further processing, or does the regex kind of swallow up the match and is handing off like an empty string or null or something to the `include` file?

How can I get the regex to match the subdirectory pattern but pass on enough info to the second `urls.py` file for my new view to get triggered?

---

So based on @Homer6's answer:

> The `include()` function in Django splits the URL string at the
> position where the match ends and passes the remainder of the string
> to the included URLconf for further processing.

I figured that the reason my new view wasn't getting triggered is that all of the regexes are set up to have `.*$` after the subdirectory, so that "matches" the entire URL *to the end of the string*, and so nothing is split off and passed on to the next URLconf.

Given a URL like

```
http://hostname/subdir1/my_new_view/some_param_value
```

what I'm looking for is to have `subdir1/` match the regex, and have `my_new_view/some_param_value` passed on through the `include` to the next URLconf.

And I got it working like this:

```
re_path(r'^subdir1/', include('subdir1.urls'))
```

The part that isn't working is the `(?i)` case insensitivity flag. The Regex101 site complains about it being at the end, and says it should be at the beginning, but if I try `r'(?i)^subdir1/'` then Django doesn't like it. Django also doesn't like `r'^subdir1/(?i)'`. Django only seems to accept the flag if it's *after* a `$`, like: `r'^subdir1/$(?i)'`, but that's the "end of string" position indicator, so then it won't match at all if there's any more to the URL than just "`subdir1/`" exactly.

So I ended up going with

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^SUBDIR1/', include('subdir1.urls')),
    re_path(r'^subdir1/', include('subdir1.urls'))
]
```

which is not ideal, but probably covers nearly every possibility. The **actual** subdirectory strings are not words, they're just short acronyms, so they are unlikely to be mixed case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `include()` function in Django splits the URL string at the position where the match ends and passes the remainder of the string to the included URLconf for further processing. When a request comes in, Django starts at the top of the `ROOT_URLCONF` and makes its way down the list of patterns, stopping at the first one that matches. The `include()` function chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf.

In your case, you have a regular expression pattern in `re_path(r'^SUBDIR1/.*$(?i)', include('subdir1.urls'))` that matches any URL starting with "SUBDIR1/", then any number of characters, and hands off to `subdir1.urls`.

Here's what happens:

1. A request comes in, let's say "SUBDIR1/my_new_view/123/"
2. Django starts at the top of the root URLconf and finds the first match: `re_path(r'^SUBDIR1/.*$(?i)', include('subdir1.urls'))`
3. Django chops off the part of the URL that matches up to "SUBDIR1/", so the remaining string is "my_new_view/123/"
4. This remaining string is passed to `subdir1.urls` for further processing.

So the issue you're facing is likely not related to the `re_path` handoff, but rather to how you've defined your URLs in your subdirectory's urls.py.

Your `subdir1.urls` file should look like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main_view, name='index'),
    path('my_new_view/<parameter>/', views.my_new_view, name='my_new_view')
]
```

If you're still facing the issue, you might want to check:

1. Your view function `my_new_view` is correctly defined in `views.py` and is taking the correct arguments.
2. The `<parameter>` in your URL pattern is correctly used in your view function.
3. Make sure you've imported the necessary modules at the top of your `urls.py` file.

Comment: "splits the URL string at the position **where the match ends** and passes the remainder of the string to the included URLconf".  Right, but that means that the `.*$` part of the regex **is** swallowing up my new URL section, because it's matching _**everything** to the end of the string_. So then nothing gets split off and passed on to the next URLconf.  So I need to figure out a better regex pattern.

Comment: Can you post some examples of what you want to match and not match and I'll update the regex pattern.

Comment: I updated the question with a bit more info.